# How to emit signal to a specific object of a QThread class in Qt?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

Assume we have created several instances from a QThread class. I need to send message from one of the thread objects to another thread object by taking into account that all thread objects are instantiated from same Qthread class. By emitting a signal, all thread objects would receive the emitted signal. But I want just a specific object (for example the object with a specific thread id) receive the signal. How can I do it in Qt?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you're inheriting from QThread, in which case, I suggest you read [this article](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/). QThread is more like a thread controller than an actual thread, so unless you're wanting to change how Qt manages threading, you're better off not inheriting from QThread.

Answer (score 2):

Signals and slots are **defined** in your class, but you **connect** signal of specific object to a slot of specific object. When you emit signal in one thread, only objects with slots connected to it would receive that signal.

Comment: Yes I connect signals to slots in my class. My class is inherited from QThread class. What I need is that when I emit a signal I do not want all objects which are instantiated from same class receive the signal. I want to emit signal to a specific object not all objects.

Comment: @m.taheri You [connect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect) specific objects, not classes. Only connected objects will receive the signal. It wouldn't make any sense otherwise.

Comment: Yes i connect objects together. But I need to emit signal to just a specific object from the set of connected objects.

Comment: You can use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` for that, but it beats me why you connect all objects and not the ones you want to receive signal.

Comment: I connect all objects together because each time the message would be exchanged between any pair of objects. So I should prepare the condition for message exchange between each pair of objects.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you might need a [QSignalMapper](http://QSignalMapper):

> this class collects a set of parameterless signals, and re-emits them with integer, string or widget parameters corresponding to the object that sent the signal.

Check out the example for more info, if you don't like to use the signal mapper you can always use a custom filter in your slot. So all other slots (not interested in the signal) can just ignore it. There is no way to filter the signal with `emit` to send it just to specified connected slots directly.

Comment: Thank you @xander but because my objects are threads and each thread has its unique identifier I doubt that QSignalMapper would be useful for my purpose. Because we should have populated the map before creation and deletion of threads. In my application the number of threads is not fixed and threads are added and removed dynamically. But I think your second offer would be useful and is the only thing I can do. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

A sender of a signal cannot determine who receives the signal, and every instance that connects to such a signal receives it. That is inherent to the observer pattern which the signal/slot mechanism implements.

I would make a mediator at which the derived threads (say A(1,..,N)) register themselves. In the mediator you need to implement the logic which message from A(i) must go to A(j). The advantage is that the A instances do not need to know each-other.  The interaction can be done by posting events which is thread-safe according to qt.